# How can I read all text when ReadAllText is unavailable?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, system.io.file

I want to assign the contents of a text file to a textbox, like so:

```
String logDirPath = 
    Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
String fullPath = logDirPath + "\\application.log";
textBoxErrLogsContents.Text = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
```

I got the "ReadAllText" from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.90).aspx), but it's not available to me.

I *am* referencing mscorlib, and I did add a "using System.IO;" but it's grayed out, while ReadAllText is fire-engine red.

Am I missing something, or do I have to skin this cat some other way in this Windows CE / Compact Framework app?

Comment: Apparently all File.ReadAllText does, apart from a few null/empty checks, is calling StreamReader.ReadToEnd method, but I guess that's unavailable too.

Comment: If you look at the docos for the class ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File_methods(v=vs.90).aspx ) it shows a little mobile device icon next to the methods that are supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compact-framework edition does not implement it. The .net version, however, is simply implemented like this:

```
public static class File
{
    public static String ReadAllText(String path)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```